# Can I place a button in one class and set a listener in another class?

Tags: android

Can I declare a button in an activity(say MainActivity.java) and in case if I need to write body for its click event in another class(Sample.java) can I set a listener in latter class(Sample.java)

Comment: that one also like Sample.java is also activity ??

Comment: Yes you can. Depends on your design.

Comment: Does that matters whether its is an activity or java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u take that layout in which that button placed is only use by First activity then make it `Public static` and call that button in secound with class name because static member of any class can access with class name itself

Comment: So you say that I create an object for MainActivity.java(which contains button) then call the button using that object right?

Comment: Works, but maybe not the better way to do.

Comment: ya but some time this type of prob we faced then we can use this type of trick dude